# Identify this iron cooking piece for me

Tags: skillet

My dad gave me this - what is it? How would I season it? What would you cook on it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It is a stove top griddle.   You set it across two burners (hobs for Brits), and heat it up.

You can use it for any griddled foods:  pancakes, hash browns, grilled sandwiches, hamburgers, steak, and so on.

The little track around the edge is to capture any juice or fat that run off the surface without making a mess.

You season it like any other cast iron pan.  It is probably easiest to do so in the oven.  You only need to season the cooking surface.

See also:

- [What's the best way to season a cast iron skillet?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/641/whats-the-best-way-to-season-a-cast-iron-skillet)
- [How to clean and maintain cast iron lids](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29895/how-to-clean-and-maintain-cast-iron-lids)
- [What oil is best for seasoning a cast-iron skillet](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13555/what-oil-is-best-for-seasoning-a-cast-iron-skillet)

Comment: Yes to the griddle ... no on only seasoning the cooking surface -- you should season the whole thing to prevent it rusting.  Maybe not 4 layers of seasoning, but one or preferably two to seal it well.